# How to make a fakeable event

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, moq

What is the proper way to raise an event using MOQ? I am currently setting the event as `virtual` and using the `Raise` method. The problem I am currently posed with is that R# yells

> Invocation of polymorphic field-like event

I am not a huge fan of creating an interface for one implementation, so I default to virtual first. Is making this an interface my only workaround?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939903/invocation-of-a-polymorphic-like-event ?

Comment: Yes, I debated that, but not sure how I feel about it. It is callling code logic when all I want is to call the raise

Comment: The recommendation to make protected methods to raise events is part of the framework design guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further discussion with a coworker, I think that an `interface` is required here. My `SUT` is verifying the result after the event, which is being faked...so there is no `OnEvent` method implementation. Nor should my SUT care about that implementation...only that the event was raised. So....unless I hear a compelling reason otherwise, this is a case where I go with the interface option.