# How does one fix "Invocation of polymorphic field-like event" when implementation depends on child class?

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper has a warning called "Invocation of polymorphic field-like event". Given these explanations, it seems like a good idea to fix it:

- [Explanation by JetBrains](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Invocation+of+polymorphic+field-like+event)
- [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939929/1269598)

However, in my case the recommended solution doesn't appear to be workable because when the event is raised, the type parameter in the child class is required. For performance reasons, I don't want to call ValueToString until ValueChanging (which is usually null) has been checked.

What's the recommended solution in this case? I have a sample of my code below. Foo's base class is split up into generic and non-generic so that I can take advantage of polymorphism in more cases.

```
public class ValueChangingEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Foo ChangingFoo { get; set; }
    public string NewValueAsString { get; private set; }

    public ValueChangingEventArgs(Foo changingFoo, string newValueAsString)
    {
        ChangingFoo = changingFoo;
        NewValueAsString = newValueAsString;
    }
}

public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract event EventHandler<ValueChangingEventArgs> ValueChanging;

    private IEnumerable<Foo> _directlyRelated;

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetRelated()
    {
        var result = new HashSet<Foo>();
        GetRelated(result);
        return result;
    }

    private void GetRelated(HashSet<Foo> resultSoFar)
    {
        foreach (var dr in _directlyRelated)
        {
            if (resultSoFar.Add(dr))
            {
                dr.GetRelated(resultSoFar);
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Foo<TValue> : Foo
{
    private TValue mValue;

    public override event EventHandler<ValueChangingEventArgs> ValueChanging;

    private void OnValueChanging(TValue newValue)
    {
        if (ValueChanging != null)
        {
            ValueChanging(this, new ValueChangingEventArgs(this, ValueToString(newValue)));
        }
    }

    protected abstract string ValueToString(TValue value);

    public void SetValue(TValue newValue)
    {
        if (!newValue.Equals(mValue))
        {
            OnValueChanging(newValue);
            mValue = newValue;
        }
    }
}

public interface IBar
{
    string PossiblyCrazyComputation();
}

public class BarFoo : Foo<IBar>
{
    protected override string ValueToString(IBar value)
    {
        return value.PossiblyCrazyComputation();
    }
}

public class BazFoo : Foo<IBaz>
```

Comment: Right now I can't see what the point of `Foo` (the non-generic base class) is. Does it work to make `ValueChangingEventArgs` generic in `TValue` and do away with `Foo` completely?

Comment: The non-generic base class exists so that I can eg. create a list of `Foo`s, or add a handler to each `Foo.ValueChanging`, without needing to know or care about each one's `TValue` argument. There is another child class that I omitted, `BazFoo : Foo<IBaz>`.

Comment: ...although now you have me thinking; in this case I could replace Foo with an interface IFoo and achieve the same thing.

Comment: The interface doesn't work, since there's a `TValue`-agnostic private method that they need to call on one another. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I seal the event override, the error goes away. Makes sense now that I think about it; now there is guaranteed to be only one implementation of the event.

```
public abstract class Foo<TValue> : Foo
{
    private TValue mValue;

    public sealed override event EventHandler<ValueChangingEventArgs> ValueChanging;
```